# Environment based file pickup in Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

Trying to use the different configuration files based on the environment.  For example

In the dev environment, I have the below file

**application-dev.yml**

```
micronaut:
  security:
    enabled: true
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        signatures:
          jwks:
            IdentityServer:
              url: 'https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks'
```

For another environment, I have the below configuration

**application.yml**

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: feteBirdApigateway
  server:
    port: 8080
    cors:
      enabled: true
  security:
    enabled: true
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        signatures:
          jwks:
            IdentityServer:
              url: 'https://falconidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks'
```

Now when I am running the application in intellj, the application is using the file `applicaiton.yml`. It should pick up the `application-dev.yml` and value `url: 'https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks'` but it is picking the value from `application.yml`. However, it should pick only that value from dev file and all the other values should be picked from `application.yml`

As per the micronaut documentation https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#environments I need to setup `micronaut.environments`

When I am running the application in the local machine, shouldn't it picked the `application-dev.yml`. How can I setup the environment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's supposed to select "dev" automatically when running from an IDE. But, you can override the environment by passing these two JVM variables in your IntelliJ Run/Debug configuration:

```
-Dmicronaut.environments=dev
-Dmicronaut.env.deduction=false
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the environment from the application.yml file? the same way SPRING framework does

Comment: @SanJaisy not to my knowledge but I'm still learning as well

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default environment in the main method

```
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.build((String[]) null).defaultEnvironments("dev").start();
    }
}
```

Reference - https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/2417